Link a row number to another reference
As a lookup table, I have a list of names and URLs like this in a Google sheet:




Name
URL




Name 1
URL 1


Name 2
URL 2


Name 3
URL 3


Name 4
URL 4


Name 5
URL 5



Now, I would like to document observations about the objects in another sheet that is constructed like this:




Metadata
Observation




Name 1
Here, we discovered nothing special.






URL 1




In the lookup table Name 1 and URL 1 are both in the same row. How can I link the cells in the protocol, so that when the cell of Name X in the lookup table is being referenced, that the cell containing URL X in the lookup table is automatically chosen in the protocol?

Solved the problem by using LOOKUP:
=LOOKUP(A1; Lookup_Sheet!A:A; Lookup_Sheet!B:B)

From the documentation: "The LOOKUP function will only work properly if data in search_range or search_result_array is sorted. Use VLOOKUP, HLOOKUP, or other related functions if data is not sorted."

Use vlookup(), like this:
=vlookup(A1, Lookup_sheet!A$2:B, columns(Lookup_sheet!A$2:B), false)

See vlookup().
